# How to Recover a wifi password?

Tags: wifi

I accidentally factory reset my windows 8.0 phone which deleted my saved password for my WiFi. How do I recover my password?

Comment: How does one *accidentally* factory-reset a phone? :P You won't be able to recover the password from the phone itself. Can you log into your router from a browser and check the password?

Comment: Also did you not enable Wi-Fi sense previously, as in my experience, known Wi-Fi networks are recovered when signing in to the phone witht he same primary account

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot recover your WiFi password from a windows mobile that too after a reset.